# Save the rendered Zend barcode in a variable CodeIgniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, zend-framework

Yes I know I am using CodeIgniter Lol

the Zend Barcode readers fine but I want to save the rendered barcode in a variable so only when I call the variable in the view (e.g. echo $myvar ) the barcode will be displayed

my code

```
    public function find_rma_authorization() {


        // get the posted term
        $rmaNumber = $this->input->post('con_rma_number');

        // use the model
        $data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_rma_authorization_data($rmaNumber);
        $data['barcode'] = $this->set_barcode($rmaNumber);


        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/rma_request_window', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }

    private function set_barcode($code)
    {
        //load library
        $this->load->library('zend');
        //load in folder Zend
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
        //generate barcode
        Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array());

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

<del>You need to return the barcode from the function:</del>

```
return Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array());
```

**Updated**

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You can try this:

Controller

```
//load library
$this->load->library('zend');
//load in folder Zend
$this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
//create barcode object
$barcode = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions);
$data['barcode'] = $barcode;
$this->load->view('posts/rma_request_window', $data);
```

View

```
// render
$barcode->render();
```

Comment: thanks when the view loads the only thing that loads is the barcode I don't want that I only want the barcode to show where I call my variable (e.g.  <td><?php echo $barcode; ?></td> ) i only want the barcode to show in a table cell

Comment: Btw you don't need to return anything

Comment: Change the render() to factory in the controller. Then call render() in the view()

Answer (score 0):

try use this code on view

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/controller_name/set_barcode/<?php echo $rmaNumber; ?>">
```